# If the function is executed while increasing memory of aws lambda, is there any effect on execution?

Tags: aws-lambda

I want to increase lambda function's memory, but I'm worry about that effect to user.

So, I tried to execute function and then I got function is executed in previous memory.

But I couldn't find this behavior on the AWS Documents and others.

Comment: Changing the memory (or changing *anything* for that matter) only affects new executions on new execution environments. If you use aliases you also need to publish new versions and change the alias for this to have any effect.

Comment: @luk2302 Thank you for your quick reply. That's why it was executed in previous memory. By the way, do you have a link of your comment?